# SQL Select Statement with sub selection

Tags: sql

I'm looking for an SQL Select statement that when given a CustomerId = 'AAAAA' will return all rows that have the same RegionId as AAAAA.

Thanks

```
CustomerId, RegionId

AAAAA,11111  
BBBBB,11111  
CCCCC,22222  
DDDDD,22222
```

Result required:

```
AAAAA,11111  
BBBBB,11111
```

Comment: Try something. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: [***Have you tried anything?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I actually did try to resolve this. I spent several hours trying different queries but it's been about 15 years since I did any SQL development back in university and I forgotten a lot. Thanks to sgeddes for his response.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this -- here's one with `in`:

```
SELECT CustomerId, RegionId
FROM YourTable
WHERE RegionId IN (
    SELECT RegionId 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE CustomerId = 'AAAAA')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select like this :

```
SELECT CustomerId, RegionId
FROM Table
WHERE RegionId = (SELECT RegionId FROM Table WHERE CustomerId = 'AAAAA')
```